# how can we add percentage like 25%, 35% ..100% to eclipse splash screen progress bar to know how much progress till there?

Tags: eclipse, swt

How can we add percentages like 25%, 35%, 100% to eclipse splash screen progress bar to know how much progress till there while seeing?

Comment: The standard SWT `ProgressBar` does not support this.

Comment: is there is another way to make progress bar progressing till end before opening workbench dialog?

Comment: If you are asking about the progress bar displayed by the normal Eclipse RCP there is nothing you can do to change it in any way. If you are building your own RCP you can try to build a better splash screen.

Comment: same like eclipse, i want to put progress bar on my splash screen. for this, I have added  org.eclipse.ui/SHOW_PROGRESS_ON_STARTUP = true in plugin_customization.ini file and in plugin.xml , i have added those entries .But i am unable to make progress bar progressing till end or showing 100% before opening dialog

Comment: The progress events that the splash screen gets are simply not enough to do this accurately. I have spent time looking at this for one of my RCPs and in my opinion it  is not fixable.